# Most efficient way to change the value of a specific tag in a DICOM file using GDCM

Tags: gdcm

I have a need to go through a set of DICOM files and modify certain tags to be current with the data maintained in the database of an external system. I am looking to use GDCM. I am new to GDCM. A search through stack overflow posts demonstrates that the anonymizer class can be used to change tag values.

[Generating a simple CT DICOM image using GDCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39150074/generating-a-simple-ct-dicom-image-using-gdcm)

My question is if this is the best use of the GDCM API or if there is a better approach for changing the values of individual tags such as patient name or accession number. I am unfamiliar with all of the API options but have a link to the API documentation. It looks like the DataElement SetValue member could be used, but it doesn't appear that there is a valid constructor for doing this in the Value class. Any assistance would appreciated. This is my current approach:

```
Anonymizer anon = new Anonymizer();
 anon.SetFile(myFile);
 anon.Replace(new Tag(0x0010, 0x0010), "BUGS^BUNNY");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite late, but maybe it would be still useful. You have not mention if you write in C++ or C#, but I assume the latter, as you do not use pointers. Generally, your approach is correct (unless you  use `System.IO.File` instead of `gdcm.File`). The value (second parameter of `Replace` function) has to be a plain string so no special constructor is needed. You should probably start with [doxygen documentation of gdcm](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/classgdcm_1_1Anonymizer.html), and there is especially [one complete example](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/CreateJPIPDataSet_8cxx-example.html#_a8). It is in C++, but there should be no problems with translation.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different ways to pad **dicom tags**:

1. **Anonymizer**

   ```
   gdcm::Anonymizer anon;
   anon.SetFile(file);   
   anon.Replace(gdcm::Tag(0x0002, 0x0013), "Implementation Version Name"); 
   //Implementation Version Name
   ```
2. **DatsElement**

   ```
   gdcm::Attribute<0x0018, 0x0088> ss;
   ss.SetValue(10.0);
   ds.Insert(ss.GetAsDataElement());
   ```